# javascript for loop executes only once

Tags: javascript

```
  for(var i=0; i < imageFiles.length; i++)
            {
                console.log('index value : ' + i)
                let item = imageFiles[i]
                let file = item.getAsFile()
                let oValue = await self.getOrientation(file)
                console.log('orientation value : ' + oValue)
            }
```

The for loop above is only executing once, could someone provide a solution that will make the loop iterate over all the files in the array ?

Comment: what's in `imageFiles`?

Comment: The only way this will only run once is if `imageFiles.length == 1`, or it blocks somewhere in the loop.

Comment: give us the whole code... what is imageFiles?

Comment: You can use `await` only in `async` function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz If it's not in an async function he'd get an error, so that's probably not the problem here.

Comment: @Barmar Correct but since kprashu will be back by tomorrow, I'm guessing :D

Comment: imageFiles is an array that has more than 1 file

Comment: this code is in the 'async onDrop' event , so no error due to await

Answer (score -1):

**From within the parentheses, you defined the variable "i" with a value of 0. As a result, i++ will return 1** and also save it to "i". You said it's only executing **once** for some reason, clearly this is part of the issue.
Check to make sure any code related to this is written as intended.

Comment: That is a really standard syntax for a basic `for` loop common to almost all languages. I think you are confusing it for a `foreach` loop, which some languages like JavaScript just give `for` an additional syntax instead of defining a new keyword.